# Why does Python 3's regular string substitution swallow characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

```
import re

base_path = "c:\\five"
print(base_path)
filename = "<data>\\a.txt"
filename = re.sub(r'(?i)<data>', base_path, filename) 
print(filename)
```

Output:

```
c:\five
c:
ive\a.txt
```

Normally it should be: `c:\five\a.txt`.

The same code doesn't do this in Python 2.

Changing it to something like the following results in the same thing.

```
reg = re.compile(re.escape('<data_path>'), re.IGNORECASE)
filename = reg.sub(base_path, filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `c:\\five` passes through `re.sub` it becomes `c:\five` (containing a `\f` form-feed character). It's a bit weird that it does this in the replacement string, but you can double-escape the backslashes as `c:\\\\five` to work around it. Or you can pass the replacement as a function, which will avoid this bit of regex-processing:

```
base_path = "c:\\five"
filename = "<data>\\a.txt"
filename = re.sub(r'(?i)<data>', lambda _: base_path, filename) 
print(filename)
```

Output: `c:\five\a.txt`

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for details:

> `repl` can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, `\n` is converted to a single newline character, `\r` is converted to a carriage return, and so forth.